# How can I made siunitx not ignore more localisation?

Tags: siunitx, german, locale

It seem's that I'm doing something wrong for localizing siunitx. What could it please be?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx} %Einheiten
\selectlanguage{german}
\sisetup{
        locale = DE ,
        per-mode = symbol, %nichts ist ^-1 symbol 
    }
%\selectlanguage{german} % oder lokal umstellen

\begin{document}
    Dieser Bereich geht von \SIrange{0}{100}{\joule}

    Dieser Bereich geht von \SIrange{0}{100}{\joule}\selectlanguage{german}
\end{document}
```

And in the attached picture there is the output using lualatex. The **to** should be a **bis** or a symbol like **–**.

[image: Output example of \SIRange]

Thank you very much.

Comment: `\documentclass[...,ngerman]{article}` and no `\selectlanguage` should work with `babel`

Comment: `german` is no valid `babel` language IIRC

Comment: Thanks that was it. Using `ngerman` it works.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @clemens I used `german` with babel and that doesn't work. Therefore using just ngerman (new german, because of a change in spell and grammar checking) localisation works now.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx} %Einheiten
\sisetup{
        locale = DE ,
        per-mode = symbol, %nichts ist ^-1 symbol 
    }
%\selectlanguage{german} % oder lokal umstellen

\begin{document}
    Dieser Bereich geht von \SIrange{0}{100}{\joule}

    Dieser Bereich geht von \SIrange{0}{100}{\joule}
\end{document}
```

[image: Code Compilation - Success]

Answer (score 3):

Localisation is probably a little misleading here.
Siunitx localisation only covers `exponent-product`, `inter-unit-product`, `output-decimal-marker`.

You will have to set `range-phrase` manually.

Comment: Well, it does work. :)

Comment: That is not related to `locale` option, that is because it looks for the `translator` package and have it translate `bis` and in this case `german` is not a supported language.  You can easily have a german doc with a UK `locale` option.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for this clarification! It makes absolutely sense. When the **to** instead of the **bis**  appeared, I tried the wrong way.